# Engineering impossible bugs?

Tags: theory

How would you engineer an impossible bug? Is it even possible?

Take a simple example: Bob needs to add commenting functionality to his popular internet blog. It gets millions of visitors a month and already has thousands of posts. How would you implement the feature if he hired you?

You would probably add a form at the end of the page which is responsible for rendering posts, right?  Its almost common sense. (Forget about security for the sake of simplicity)

However, that solution assumes way too much about how Bob's blog works.

Let's say that the person who made Bob's blog hated Bob. He wanted to make a system where no new features could be implemented without completely rewriting it from scratch.

How would you create a system like that if you were the one that hated Bob? You aren't limited to a specific language,  framework, operating system, server software, architecture, or anything. All you need to do is provide working blog pages to clients that connect to your server.

Also assume Bob will do whatever you tell him to. If he has to send in his new hand-written blog posts by carrier pigeon to an offshore processing center, then he will do it.

And before anyone asks, NO, I am NOT asking this question because I want to screw over a client. I think of this like an exercise. We're used to engineering code that isn't supposed to break, but how would we do engineering code that isn't supposed to work? Just like bugs are inevitable, are solutions equally inevitable? Is it just as hard to create  inverted code like this as it is to write regular code? If we can create code that can't be fixed, does it mean we can create code that can't be broken?

Comment: Interesting question with the right tags, but this is probably more suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Bugs are unintentional.  If you are trying to make something difficult to use, then it's a feature, not a bug!

Answer (score 0):

Because the blog platform itself is fairly expendable, I would think that the only sort of bug that irreversibly cripples Bob's web-presence would have to be a bug targeted at either the content, or at Bob himself. Some examples of this would be placing the only terminal that allows Bob to post in a cage full of lions, or convincing the internet to DDoS every blog written on the same topic as Bob's blog.

That said, as long as Bob is a citizen of the free world where free internet access in public cafes and libraries abounds, I don't think it will ever be possible to introduce a bug so terrible that Bob's blog cannot be published.

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say that the person who made Bob's blog hated Bob. He wanted to make a system where no new features could be implemented without completely rewriting it from scratch.
>   How would you create a system like that if you were the one that hated Bob?

I would create the blogging system in [Malbolge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbolge).